# DbContext not disposing

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a test which I expect to fail and yet it doesn't:

```
   [TestMethod]
    public void FillListOfSecurityExchangesRepository()
    {
      var qry = new SecurityExchangeQueryContext
      {
           QueryType = SecurityExchangeQueryType.FillAllWithMarketsAndStocks
      };
      using (var ctx = new EquitiesDbContext())
      {
          var r = new SecurityExchangeRepository(ctx);
          r.Read(qry);
          r.Dispose();
      }
      Assert.IsTrue(qry.Exchanges.Count > 0);    
   }
```

I expect this to fail because in the repository I'm not calling ToList on the query, then upon return I call Dispose of the context.

(I actually call this twice, redundantly, in the code above as it wasn't failing with just r.Dispose() which in turn Disposes the context.)

Here is what the Read method of the repository calls:

```
    protected virtual void FillAllWithMarketsAndStocks(SecurityExchangeQueryContext qctx)
    {
        this.Fill(() => qctx.Exchanges.AddRange(this.DbSet.OrderBy(exch => exch.Name).Include("StockMarkets.Stocks")),
            "void FillAllWithMarketsAndStocks(SecurityExchangeQueryContext qctx) failed.");
    }
```

(There are some bits abstracted away with an Extensions class but nothing that affects the context.)

Since I'm calling this.DbSet.OrderBy without a ToList then each Exchange must still be referencing the DbSet Exchanges of the context.

So I expected it to fail since in the TestMethod I don't do an Assert / Count until after I dispose of the Context but it continues to pass. Using a Watch I can see the Context is still alive and kicking even after exiting the using block. I can also access properties of an Exchange so it's not just random blob in the Collection.

```
 var sm = qry.Exchanges[0].StockMarkets.First();
```

Comment: Based on your comment, try using `Concat` or `Union` instead of `AddRange`